# PyQT5 slot with Matplotlib has no effect

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a slot method that will clear a matplotlib figure that is part of QtWidget. I have tried with both Python 3.6 and 3.5  on windows 7 and 10 and i get same behaviour.

My issue is that i can perfectly clear the figure when calling the wipe method from the main block of code or within the class drawing the figure. But whenever this very same method is called as a slot to a PyQT signal, slot is actually activated but the call to fig.clf() does not clear the figure.

The code below shows the issue :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, QSizePolicy,QWidget,QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg  import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


class GraphPopulate(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6,4))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.07, 0.16, 0.95, 0.95])  # fraction of figure size  #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        x = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]
        y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        self.plt = self.ax.plot(x, y)

        # self.wipe()  # OK This one works as well
        # self.plt.close(self.fig) # close the app, does not only clear figure

    def wipe(self):
        print('wipe start')
        # del self.fig  # close the app  on second call, does not only clear figure !!
        # self.plt.close(fig) # close the app, does not only clear figure
        rc = self.fig.clf()
        print('return code from clf()  '+ str(rc))
        print('wipe stop')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create main window
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

    # create widget to be used by MathPlotlib
    WidgetMatplot = QWidget(MainWindow)
    WidgetMatplot.setGeometry(QRect(10, 40, 500, 500))

    # create Push Button with clicked signal linked to GraphPopulate.wipe() slot
    button = QPushButton(MainWindow)
    button.setText("Push Me !")

    # add widget to vertical box layout
    hbox = QVBoxLayout(MainWindow)
    hbox.addWidget(WidgetMatplot)
    hbox.addWidget(button)

    g = GraphPopulate(WidgetMatplot)

    button.pyqtConfigure(clicked=g.wipe)  # NOT OK !!!!!!! g.wipe is triggered as prints statements show
                                          #  on console but self.fig.clf() has no effect

    MainWindow.show()
    # g.wipe()  # OK
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've put comments on statements that if uncommented are actually clearing the figure or closing the whole app.

Looks like the "matplotlib context" is not the same when called from the signa-slot connect than from other calls.

May be i miss something trivial. If so sorry for that but i couldn't find any direction to investigate by myself...so i rely on you guys to spot it out.

Thanks - Thibault

Answer (score 0):

In your code the figure is successfully cleared. You just don't see it because nobody told the figure that it needs to be redrawn.

If you redraw the figure, you'll see that it is indeed empty.

```
def wipe(self):
    self.fig.clf()
    self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Thanks ! then how is it that the g.wipe() in main block after  MainWindow.show() do not need such drawing instruction ? because it is included in the main progam loop and not the slot method ?

Comment: The figure is first drawn on `app.exec_()`, that is *after* you call `wipe`. So at this point the figure is already cleared. When you push the button, the figure has already been drawn so you need to draw it again to see the changes.

Comment: ok thank you i was wrongly assuming drawing was done at show () function execution time. Hence my question